# React native performance issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using coincap api's to first fetch Data of about 1500+ crypto currency and then Web-socket to update the updated value of crypto Currency.

I a using redux to manage my state here

Inside My `componentDidMount()`, I am calling a **redux action** `fetchCoin` which fetches the value of the coin

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCoin()
  }
```

And then In `return` I am doing something like this

```
 <FlatList
           data={this.state.searchCoin ? displaySearchCrypto : this.props.cryptoLoaded}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <CoinCard
              key={item["short"]}
              coinShortName = {item["short"]}
              coinName = {item["long"]}
              coinPrice = {item["price"].toFixed(2)}
              percentChange = {item["perc"].toFixed(2)}
              />
```

Then I have a web-socket which updates the value of cryptocurrency like this

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.updateCoinData || this.updateCoinData.length < 1 ) {
      this.updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded];
     this.setState({updateCoinData: true})
    }
      this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
      for (let i=0; i< this.updateCoinData.length; i++) {

        if (this.updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {

        //Search for changed Crypto Value
       this.updateCoinData[i]["perc"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["perc"]
       this.updateCoinData[i]["price"] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']['price']

        //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
        this.props.updateCrypto(this.updateCoinData);

          }
        }
      })
  }
```

Now, While this work, the problem is that this is slowing my app like hell since whenever the socket sends new data, it has to render every component and hence events like touch and search takes lot of time to execute. **[Update]** It turns out my app is rendering something even If i remove socket connection, **check out update 2**

**[Question:]** What should I do so that I can improve the performance of App? (Something like not using state or using DOM to update my app and so on).

**[Update 1:]** I am using https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto
And these two are js files where all the logic is happening 
https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/container/cryptoContainer.js
https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/components/CoinCard.js
I have also move from map to Flatlist.

**[Update: 2]** I found that there are **endless render happening** inside my App which is probably keeping my thread busy (**I mean it is endless & unnecessarily passing props**). I asked the same question on separate [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213596/infinite-render-in-react) but didn't received a proper response and since it is related to performance, I thought about putting a bounty on it here.

Please check this thread: [infinite Render in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213596/infinite-render-in-react)

**[Answer Update:]** While there are many great answers here, Just in case someone wants to understand how it worked, You could probably clone my repository and go back to **before** this [commit](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/commit/f395c7cda912599049d3448204a2b8a5660d6cb0). I have linked the commit to the point where my problems was solved (so you might need to go back and see what I was doing wrong). Also, All the answers were very useful and not hard to comprehend so you should definitely go through them.

Comment: Is there a reason for opening and closing sockets? Is there a chance you can make changes in the server side APIs?

Comment: @BilboBaggins Nope! Coincap provides socket connection so we can't change. There is a reason for opening socket but thinking it that way, I can eliminate disconnect method.

Comment: he wrote about opening socket in `componentDidUpdate` - problem already solved in answers, comments and repo (@KuchBhi update question) - but yuo're still adding a new handler there :P - see my update

Comment: Because I think it is an overhead to open a socket every time, you have to if your app has lost connection etc.. furthermore what I thought was this, if only those things which have changed since the last call, if I can obtain only those then I can update only those components rendering it (NOT a react expert), not the whole list. Is there a way to do so? Just thinking aloud here.

Comment: @BilboBaggins, Xadam already mentioned that in his answer and I fixed it in repo but forgot to update it here. Updated my Question,  :)

Comment: Ya got that I just read the answers :) my bad .. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Bhojendra Rauniyar said, you should use shouldComponentUpdate in CoinCard. You probably also want to change your FlatList, your downsized sample has the FlatList in a ScrollView, this causes the FlatList to fully expand, thus rendering all it's items at once.

```
class cryptoTicker extends PureComponent {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
        this.props.fetchCoin()
        this.props.CurrencyRate()

        this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {

            for (let i=0; i< this.updateCoinData.length; i++) {

                if (this.updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {

                    //Search for changed Crypto Value
                    this.updateCoinData["short"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["short"]
                    this.updateCoinData[i]["perc"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["perc"]
                    this.updateCoinData[i]["price"] = tradeMsg["message"]['msg']['price']

                    //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
                    this.props.updateCrypto(this.updateCoinData);

                }
            }
        })

      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        // Fill with redux data once
        if (this.updateCoinData.length < 1 && newProps.cryptoLoaded) {
            this.updateCoinData = [...newProps.cryptoLoaded];
        }
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
                <Header/>
                <FlatList
                    style={{flex:1}}
                    data={this.props.cryptoLoaded}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.short}
                    initialNumToRender={50}
                    windowSize={21}
                    removeClippedSubviews={true}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                        <CoinCard
                            index={index}
                            {...item}
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class CoinCard extends Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return this.props.price !== nextProps.price || this.props.perc !== nextProps.perc
    }

    render() {
        console.log("here: " + this.props.index);

        return (
            <View>
                <Text> {this.props.index} = {this.props.long} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but still endless re renders of some stuff again and again . 
You can check this -> https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto

Comment: created a pull request for you.
Fixes:
- Set only a single socket callback in componentDidMount(), like I said in my previous answer
- Fill this.updateCoinData with redux data once using componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Your update worked hence I market it answer but I am still curious as when you said **Set only a single socket callback in componentDidMount()** You changed the lifecycle of from `componentDidUpdate` to `componentDidMount()` so what do you exactly mean by that? Also, Please update your answer on this post accordingly

Comment: componentDidUpdate gets called each time redux updates the props. If you set `this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {})` in there it will add a new callback each time. Then when a new message arrives it will be processed by each previously assigned callback, and each callback will trigger a new update through the redux store. So you will only want to set the callback one time when the view is first loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Each time your component updates it starts a new socket which results in a memory leak and will cause `this.props.updateCrypto(updateCoinData);` to be called multiple times for the same data. This can be fixed by opening the socket in `componentDidMount()` and closing it in `componentWillUnmount()`.

You can also buffer multiple record updates and change the FlatList data in one go every couple of seconds.

Edit, working example (App.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.currencies = {};
        this.state      = {
            currenciesList: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket = SocketIOClient('https://coincap.io');

        this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
            const time = new Date();

            // Store updates to currencies in an object
            this.currencies[tradeMsg.message.msg.short] = {
                ...tradeMsg.message.msg,
                time: time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':' + time.getSeconds(),
            };

            // Create a new array from all currencies
            this.setState({currenciesList: Object.values(this.currencies)})
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.socket.disconnect();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.currenciesList}
                extraData={this.state.currenciesList}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.short}
                renderItem={({item}) => <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{item.time}</Text>
                    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{item.short}</Text>
                    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{item.perc}</Text>
                    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{item.price}</Text>
                </View>}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Socket data needs to be updated once the data from http://coincap.io/front hence I am calling it in componentDidUpdate And since socket is sending data every second hence I decided to got for componentDidUpdate (Not an expert here, so I might be missing something here?)

Comment: You only need to open the socket once. The `socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {` will then automatically be called each time the server sends new data (which is roughly every second).

Comment: basebase, Got it but then how will you call it? because it's a callback. Can you please include the demonstration in your example as well?

Comment: Included an example: open the socket in the component which contains the FlatList, update state in the socket callback

Comment: @basebase, I did something like this https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/container/cryptoContainer.js  instead of copying your code exactly. 
In this,   `componentDidMount() {` this is coming out to be an empty object var `updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded];` Do you have any idea why this could be happening? I need to use redux here (I guess this isn't because of redux).

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check it when you got free time.

Answer (score 6):

There're many standard ways to improve react app performance, the most common:

- use usual react optimizations (shouldComponentUpdate, PureComponent - read docs)
- use virtual lists (limit visible parts of data)

## In this case I would add:

**Don't process data before optimizations** - f.e. formatting data that didn't changed is at least unnecessary. You can insert intermediate component (optimization layer) that will pass/update formatted data into `<CoinCard />` only on 'raw data' change.

**[You might not need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) at all** (store data in state) when data is used in one place/simple structure. Of course you can use redux for other globally **shared** app state (f.e. filtering options).

Use `<FlatList />` (react-native), search for sth more suitable?

## UPDATE

**Some code was changed in mean time** (repo), at this time (08.09) one issue still exist and probably causing memory leaks.

You're calling `this.socket.on` on each `componentDidUpdate` call (wrongly coded conditions) - continuously adding a new handler!

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  // call all ONLY ONCE afer initial data loading
  if (!this.state.updateCoinData && !this.props.cryptoLoaded.length) {
    this.setState({updateCoinData: true}) // block condition
    this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {

      // slice() is faster, new array instance
      // let updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded]; 
      let updateCoinData = this.props.cryptoLoaded.slice();

      for (let i=0; i<updateCoinData.length; i++) {
        //Search for changed Crypto Value
        if (updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {

          // found, updating from message
          updateCoinData[i]["long"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["long"]
          updateCoinData[i]["short"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["short"]
          updateCoinData[i]["perc"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["perc"]
          updateCoinData[i]["mktcap"] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']["mktcap"]
          updateCoinData[i]["price"] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']['price']

          //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
          this.props.updateCrypto(updateCoinData);

          // record found and updated, no more looping needed
          break;
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Minor errors**: initial fetching states set to true in reducers.

**Searching for performance issues I would look at `<CoinCard />`:**

- make it PureComponent;
- `increased` and `decreased` aren't required to be saved at state which forces unnecessasry render calls;
- I would use update time (not saved in state, just passed as prop in parent and only for updated rows, within `updateCoinData` in code above) and derive direction (check for 0 and sign only) of difference (**already calculated in `perc`**) **only for visible items** (from render) and **only during time limit** (difference between render time and data update prop). `setTimeout` can be used, too.
- finally removing `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentDidUpdate` and `shouldComponentUpdate` should (highly?) improve performance;

Comment: **1.** What do you mean in your point "Don't process data before optimizations" Can you please explian this in details? with an example?
**2**. I would need redux since I intend to use this at other places as well in my app.
**3** Thanks for mentioning about `<FlatList />`

Comment: [**Updated Answer**]:  -> **1** `this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {` have a callback, Where else should I call it?

**performance issues I would look at `<CoinCard />`**, I was unable to comprehend the second part/point. Can you please include example for that as well?

Comment: Some statements was related to earlier code (f.e. redux before publishing repo link or code update). Formatting data for 1000s of records vs. formatting only visible records (from passed raw data) - doing this in `renderItem` fixes this. `socket.on` (check how many times is fired) is already fixed in my code above (proper conditions in `componentDidUpdate`). `<CoinCard />` had unneccessary state changes (forcing additional `render`) while it was simple to do w/o state (conditions in `render`).

Answer (score 2):

When rendering Flatlist you should consider using `PureComponent` or utilizing `shouldComponentUpdate` hook to update only if required.

From the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists):

> If your application renders long lists of data (hundreds or thousands of rows), we recommended using a technique known as “windowing”. This technique only renders a small subset of your rows at any given time, and can dramatically reduce the time it takes to re-render the components as well as the number of DOM nodes created.

Take a deep drive to this [performance guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action).

If you still want some advanced look through, then I will recommend you to look into the following threads:

[FlatList and VirtualizedList Scroll performance is laggy after 30+ rows](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413)

[Performance problems with react when using a big list](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/performance-problems-with-react-when-using-a-big-list/3432/12)

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot for your answer. 
I already implemented PureComponent, I am reading and implementing **windowing** now :) 
My major curiosity/worry right now is finding what is causing unnecessary render.
Can you *please *  go though this thread [**Update 2 of this thread**] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213596/infinite-render-in-react

Comment: CoinCard should implement PureComponent or utilize shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: Inside my coincard I did something like this   `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

        if (this.props == nextProps || this.state == nextState)  {
            console.log("inside should compoenent not to update")
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log("Component Would update")
            return true; 
        }

    }`  Now my console is filled with endless **console.log("inside should compoenent not to update")**

Comment: Thanks, Going though it. 
I know it is a lot to ask but if you got few minutes to spare, can you clone the see if you could find and rectify the problem behind those unnecessary render?

Comment: Okay, I'll think about it tomorrow to clone and find the issue. (If I could manage time).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, I just found an issue with FlatList -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15990

Comment: There's no interesting topic so I din't link in my post.

Comment: I just took a quick look into the commit, I think you're doing something wrong here: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchCoin, updateCrypto, CurrencyRate})(cryptoTicker);` See this post for little help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024419/react-redux-state-change/52024509#52024509 which might also drive into your problem

Comment: Doing! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my github with the real project code working, had to change it so the onlookers won't have to spend endless time understanding it.
Also, I guess I might need extra hand here, I didn't get what I might be doing wrong? I am getting my data.

Comment: Did you got time to go through it?

Comment: Sorry, not yet. What's your progress, BTW? (I think, couldn't manage time to check due to some pressure.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never do API calls in React's componentWillMount() lifecycle method, instead it should be done in componentDidMount().

   *Check out this very neat article on lifecycle methods and what should be done in which method:* https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d.

> Many will be tempted to use this function in order to send a request to fetch data and expect the data to be available before the initial render is ready. This is not the case — while the request will be initialized before the render, it will not be able to finish before the render is called.

2. Instead of creating a socket to update the coinData, you might want to make use of redux subscibe/unsubscribe methods.

Comment: ComponentDidMount is also triggering endless trigger but I read the same article and changed it to componentDidMount. 
Can you please include the example of redux subscribe/unsubscribe methods?
Also, I would be so grateful if you could check out this thread as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213596/infinite-render-in-react (I mentioned this in **update 2** of the current post)

Comment: I have checked the other question, will clone the repo and see what's happening. 
In the meantime, you can check this short tutorial by Dan Abramov for the use of subscribe - https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe