# React Redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

`this.props.authState` stays the same although I'm dispatching an action in my `componentDidMount` function:

```
componentDidMount() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        dispatch(updateAuthState('AUTHENTICATED'));
      }
  }

render() {
 <div>{this.props.authState}</div>
}

Home.propTypes = {
    authState: PropTypes.string
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        authState: state.authState
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {

  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

the output is NO_AUTH (the initial value of `authState`)

Reducer:

```
export function authState(state = "NO_AUTH", action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'AUTH_STATE':
            return action.authState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

any idea why?

Comment: Please share your reducer here

Comment: because You are dispatching in componentDidMount which this method gets called only once per component

Comment: No it’s not an issue with componentDidMount(). It won’t be mounted again unless it is unmounted before

Comment: please post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently dispatching directly inside the componentDidMount which isn't mapped into:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

This should do the job:

```
componentDidMount() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        this.props.onUpdateAuthState('AUTHENTICATED');
      }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onUpdateAuthState: function(authState) {
      dispatch(updateAuthState(authState));
    }
  }
};
```

Now, this will get the authState:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        authState: state.authState
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re mutating the state then component will not be re rendered. You need to return `{...state, authState}` from your reducer.
And you verify your updated state in

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
  {
   }
```

I hope this would solve the issue.

Comment: You only use `cwrp` if you have internal component state that you need to sync with props dynamically. Otherwise you don't need `cwrp` as `mapStateToProps` is going to assign new props thus trigger component rerender with all update lifecycles.

Comment: I just stated it to verify the state changes, didn’t recommend to use it.