# Why not dispatch directly into store from action creator redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am building an app using redux and react-native.

I am curious about a pattern which I use. I have encountered no downsides however I haven't seen it in any tutorials which makes me wonder why nobody does it.

Instead of passing action creators as props in the connect function like

```
 connect(mapStateToProps,{ func1, func2 })(Component);
```

I imported the app store inside of the module where I declare the functions in the first place:

```
import { AppStore } from '../App';
const actionCreator = () => {
   doSomethng();
   appStore.dispatch({ type: 'Action' });
};
```

This to me makes it easier to do async actions because I need no middleware:

```
import { AppStore } from '../App';
const actionCreator = async () => {
   await doSomethng();
   appStore.dispatch({ type: 'Action' });
};
```

I did this because of the js-lint error `'no-shadow'`. It made me realise that in order to use it I had to import the action creators in the component file, and then pass it as a prop to the connect function in order for the action creator to have access to dispatch.

```
import { actionCreator1, actionCreator2 } from './actionCreators';

const myComponent = (props) => {
   const { actionCreator1, actionCreator2 } = props; //shadowed names
   return (
      <Button onPress={actionCreator1} />
   );
};

export default connect({}, { actionCreator1, actionCreator2 })(myComponent)
```

In my version I just import it once but do not pass it to connect. This eliminates the need to shadow names.

```
import { actionCreator1, actionCreator2 } from './actionCreators';

const myComponent = (props) => {
   return (
      <Button onPress={actionCreator1} />
   );
};

export default connect({})(myComponent)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075012/2138752

Comment: I see that the use of the connect function is addressed with respect to mapStateToProps. I agree with that but I do not understand how it relates to dispatch. I am having difficulty understanding the 'potential problems'. I can't seem to wrap my brain around them. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like that you try to find your own solutions to your specific problems.  It's the sign of an engineer, just in this case this isn't the solution.

I think the idea of how Redux teaches you to do things is not intended to be canonized.  You have the ability to put a dispatcher on your props because it allows things to be transparent, meaning that things are bound outside of your class and injected in.  You have hidden your store dependency by directly referencing it in some other files.  It's no longer as obvious how your application works with regards to the workflow.  Another react developer would be confused, I suppose that's the major downside.

If you're ok with those aspects what you're doing is fine.  Fine as in, it gets the job done, but not "fine" in that it embraces concepts like [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see how it might be confusing to another react developer at first glance. I don't understand how this violates the SRP. I thought I was embracing it since I was removing a responsibility from my react components, they no longer send data to the store themselves but only receive them. Or at least they aren't concerned with dispatching actions so much as they are with simply calling functions.

Comment: Well connect is already creating this separation. It may be in the same file as your class but it isn't inside your class!  You are using your class and connect to compose something new, letting each handle their own concerns, at no point do you need to know about the store except when it's first set up in the composition root.  

Imagine you wanted to change your application store.... just rename it.  You've now got to update all of your action files, whereas using the traditional method they could have remained unchanged because you were meant to not consume the store directly.