# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined (reactjs) (very simpel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I followed this beginner tutorial on redux: [text](https://daveceddia.com/how-does-redux-work/), [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX3KeP7v7Kg).

Everything works with the exception of the increment button. When I click the increment button I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

See what happens: [gif](https://gyazo.com/54fb49026d3694aee43c502982eab44c)

Why am I getting that error when I did "mapStateToProps"?

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Test_left from './eo_app.jsx';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from "redux";

const initialState = {
    count: 21
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('reducer', action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return { count: 55 };
        default:
                return state;
    }
};

const store = createStore(reducer);


const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Test_left />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('target'));

//// store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT' }); this will work as expected
```

eo_app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Test_left extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    increment () {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }); // <== ERROR IS RAISED HERE
  }

    render() {
        console.log('props:', this.props)
        return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h1> WE GOT RENDERED </h1>
                    <h1>{this.props.count}</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.increment}> Increment </button>
                </React.Fragment>
        )
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    count: state.count
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test_left);
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

There are actually two issues:

The first is that you need to bind your `increment` function to the class itself. This is a common "gotcha," you can read about it here - https://reactjsnews.com/es6-gotchas

The second is, with `react-redux` and the `connect` function, you need to map the redux `dispatch` function to a prop. This is done with a second function you pass in your `connect` call: `mapDispatchToProps`.

Yours might look like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleClick: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
});
```

With those two changes, your component would then look like

```
class Test_left extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Bind `increment` to this class's scope
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    increment () {
        // Use newly created prop function to dispatch our action to redux
        this.props.handleClick();
    }

    // ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    count: state.count
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleClick: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test_left);
```

Comment: It worked when I bound the increment in the constructor without I had to connect mapDispatchToProps.

Answer (score 1):

When you do: `this.props.dispatch`, it will call dispatch mapped with the connect. But you don't have map for the dispatch:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test_left);
```

So, replace preceding code with:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToState)(Test_left);
```

Now, define the function for mapDispatchToState and call the dispatch there.

---

The key issue I forgot to mention is that make sure to bind `this` because `this` will be undefined when you call inside a method. Or, you may assign a [public class method](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
increment = () => { // now, this will be accessible
```

---

PS: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024419/react-redux-state-change/52024509#52024509) why you need to use map dispatch instead of directly dispatching it. It makes sense not to mix the connect maps with direct dispatch.

Comment: That's weird, the tutorial didn't do that: https://daveceddia.com/how-does-redux-work/ (scroll to the button and look at the code)... Neither does the video: https://youtu.be/sX3KeP7v7Kg?t=5m24s

Comment: If I try to "define a public class method" I get unexpected token. *It points at the first equal symbol on the line. screenshot: https://gyazo.com/1a6d9c66a92523e405a02f227828fc5c

Comment: @RyanCameron interesting, I wonder if `connect` always exposes `dispatch` for you to dispatch whatever action you may want. In either case, generally people will create that second `mapDispatchToProps` to keeps things more centralized. Also, in the tutorial video, the reason why the author does not need the `this.func = this.func.bind(this)` call in his constructor, is he uses [ES7 class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/), so instead of writing `increment() { ... }`, he writes `increment = () => { ... }`

Comment: I am using ES6 jsx, I guess that is the reason why.

Comment: To use ES7 class properties, you need to enable the Babel transform I mentioned above. Or, you can just use call `this.func = this.func.bind(this)` within your constructor for any functions that reference `this` (i.e., the class) within them.