# The best way to maintain immutability of state of redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**/reducers/index.js**

```js
import * as types from '../actions/ActionTypes';

var initialState = {
    categoryName: 'default name redux'
};



function re_modifyCategoryName(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.MODIFY_CATEGORY_NAME :
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                categoryName: action.categoryNewName
            });

        default:
            return state;

    }
}

export {re_modifyCategoryName}
```

I definitely check `state` of `redux store` is updated by Redux-dev-tool and redux-logger,

[image]

[image]

but `mapStateToProps` is not being called.

---

**PresentationalComponent.js**

```js
... 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("inside category name", state.categoryName);
    return {categoryName: state.categoryName}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AnswerEachCategory);
...
```

When the page is rendered first time, as you can see `mapStateToProps`, `"inside category name", state.categoryName` is shown in `console` and `presentational component` correctly get `props.categoryName` from `initialState` of `redux store`. However, why the change in `redux store` didn't trigger `mapStateToProps`??

Is this problem related with immutability of `state` of redux store?

---

**Container.js**

```js
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    onModifyCategoryName: (categoryNewName) => {
        dispatch(actions.modifyCategoryName(categoryNewName))
    }
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ModifyCategoryNameModal)
...
```

Comment: How are you dispatching? This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024419/react-redux-state-change/52024509#52024509

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar If I change `state` of `redux store` correctly, Does it mean that I use `dispatch(action)` well?

Comment: The linked answer has explained it.