# FlatList is not stable when list size is high - react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My application's react-native version is 0.51.0.

When the **flatlist** size is not so high, it is loading without any issue. **(figure_01)**.

But when list size is high(here I have 55 items in the list), It is showing empty rows instead of values. **(figure_02)**.

I checked the list items and there are no any null values or empty items.
And also checked with more devices.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

figure_01

[image: figure_01]

figure_02

[image: figure_02]

```
<ScrollView style={Styles.scroll_main} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}} >
                <View style={Styles.container_listview}>

                    <FlatList
                        data={ this.state.flatListItems }
                        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                        renderItem={

                                ({item}) => <View style={Styles.item_m_log}>
                                <Content style={Styles.model_container}>
                                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                        <View>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Card Number </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.cardNumber} </Text></View>
                                            </View>
                                          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Vehicle Number </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.vehicleNo}</Text></View>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Date/Time </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.deviceTimeStamp}</Text></View>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Amount </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.price} </Text></View>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Mileage  </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.mileageKm}</Text></View>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_m_log} uppercase={false}> •  Fuel Station </Text></View>
                                                <View style={Styles.txt_model_details_user_pro_view}><Text style={Styles.txt_model_details_m_log} uppercase={false}> : {item.stationName} </Text></View>
                                            </View>

                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                </Content>
                                </View>
                        }
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try simplifying and just show a <Text>content</Text> for each item.  I'm guessing that one of your subfields is null which is causing an error and returning null for the renderer for that cell.

Comment: You're trying to render the `FlatList` object many times `ScrollView -> FlatList -> ScrollView`. Checkout this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213596/infinite-render-in-react/52257023#52257023) to optimize the Flatlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in Content tag which used inside the renderItem method, according to [native-base documentation](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#anatomy-headref) you can only use one Content tag inside a screen, remove the Content tag and list will load perfectly. And also you don't have to wrap the Flatlist around a ScrollView since flatlist already inherits ScrollView props.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I am trying to use big list it will render the list element but did not display it.

My solution:

1. Give absolute height to the list item
2. Use a third party plugin, like flatlist