# Avoid re-rendering of SectionList rows components in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I was working on optimisation part and found that, Section list is rendering child components even though they have no change. On research, I found that u have to pass a key which uniquely identifies a section to avoid re-rendering of child components.

I did pass unique key's to child components but even than its getting re-rendered.

UPDATE: Code Below

I am using react-redux for state management.

render:

```
<SectionList
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
            sections={this.getSectionListData()}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        />
```

renderItem:

```
if (conditionX)
 return <XComponent data={this.getDataX()} action={this.doSomethingToX} />
else if (conditionY)
 return <YComponent data={this.getDataY()} action={this.doSomethingToY} />
else if (conditionZ)
 return <ZComponent data={this.getDataZ()} action={this.doSomethingToZ} />
else 
return <View/>

getDataX = () => return this.props.reduxState.dataX;

getDataY = () => return this.props.reduxState.dataY;

getDataZ = () => return this.props.reduxState.dataZ;

doSomethingToX/Y/Z : Updates the reducer values X/Y/Z respectively.
```

Initially I don't have any values for X/Y/Z in reducer, but If I update the value X, the child component (i.e. `YComponent`, `ZComponent`) also gets re-rendered.

Any suggestion on how to avoid this un-ncessary rendering.

Comment: I think you use state to render sectionlist's items. it maybe occur problem. can you post codechip here?

Comment: Checkout the following necessary [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257023/6606831)