# React is very slow when I put button to every cells in hundred rows

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 300 rows and each row has 15 columns. and every cell has button to add data. to your precious time, I made a fiddle.

https://codesandbox.io/s/y0j4w79mz9

```
// rows is 300 length array. 
// cols is 15 length array. 
// you can see whole code above sandbox

<Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>{months.map(el => <TableCell>{el}</TableCell>)}</TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                {cols.map((el, colIndex) => (
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    <Button
                      onClick={() =>
                        alert("You clicked " + rowIndex + " X " + colIndex)
                      }
                    >
                      Click Me
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
```

Each cell can has one of ['Good', 'Marginal', 'Bad'].

Actually first time I want to use like [React Datasheet](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet), but I think this has possible to users input wrong value like `Gooood` so I changed to this way to `Button` => show `Menus` for `Good/Marginal/Bad`.

In such case, How can I speed up rendering time? Is there a way to declare `Button` just once?

I think it not huge... just 300 rows. Should I use another library? Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020855/react-native-performance-issue)

Comment: You should use https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized to effectively maintain large list efficiently performance wise.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar this has nothing to do with with react native.

Comment: @AdeelImran the dup post will obviously help the OP. Retracted my vote though.

Comment: I had extremely better results when moved to a data grid instead of 'map'ing every parameter. I did try @javed's solution too. It did help but not as good as a datagrid for around 200 rows and 10 fields

Answer (score 1):

The way its done above

```
<Button
 onClick={() => alert("You clicked " + rowIndex + " X " + colIndex) }>
   Click Me
</Button>
```

Will make a new function every time a Button component is rendered and every re-render will make a new function in the memory.

Instead you can use function references and pass a it to the `Button` onClick handler.

There was a good [blog post](https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/cache-your-react-event-listeners-to-improve-performance-14f635a62e15) about it, <strike>which I will update once I find it.</strike>

In short, use function references and for better performance, memoize the function so that you dont have to create the same function again for each render.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then passing a closure onClick to each button, pass same function to each button and such that button is implemented as follows.

```
class CustomButton extends React.Component{
  shouldComponentUpdate({children}){
    if(children !== this.props.children){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  onClick=(e)=>{
    const {onClick, rowIndex, colIndex} = this.props;
    onClick(e, {rowIndex, colIndex});
  }
  render(){
    return <button {...this.props} onClick={this.onClick}/>
  }
}
```